# Не могу распарсить JSON без ключа

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

Пытаюсь распарсить JSON [такого вида](http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=moon&apikey=1113844f)

В активити, но он не принимает никакие значения. Делаю под Volley, мучаюсь уже третий день.
Как его распарсить, чтобы хотябы имя отображалось. В идеале еще и картинка, под Picasso пытался, но тоже шляпа вышла. Проблема в том, что в интернете есть только с ArrayList где есть ключ главный, у меня его в JSON нет

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    titleName = findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
    String textName = name.replace(" ", "+");
    String text = url + textName + apiKey;
    //title.setText(text);
    getMovies();


}

private void getMovies() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("Name");
    String textName = name.replace(" ", "+");
    String text = url + textName + apiKey;
    Log.d("text", text);
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, text,
             null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                String title = jsonObject.getString("Title");
                String year = jsonObject.getString("Year");
                Movie movie = new Movie();
                movie.setTitle(title);
                movie.setYear(year);

                titleName.setText(title);

            }

            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //В случае ошибки вывидется стек ошибок
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}
```

Layout:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/posterImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_height="200dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
            android:text="title"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yearTextView"
            android:text="year"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/genreTextView"
            android:text="genre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/directorTextView"
            android:text="director"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/runtimeTextView"
            android:text="runtime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/plotTextView"
            android:text="plot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Что значит "он не принимает никакие значения" и кто он? Также, возможно, вам стоит перейти на другой стэк технологий. Например OkHttp(+Retrofit)+Gson для сетевых запросов + парсинга JSON и Glide для картинок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> он не принимает никакие значения

Потому что в `onResponse` вы создаёте пустой объект:
`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();`
и работаете с ним, а пришедший из запроса `JSONObject response` игнорируете.
Не факт, что это единственная ошибка вашего кода, но надо пробовать разбираться по порядку.

```java
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                String title = response.getString("Title");
                String year = response.getString("Year");
                Movie movie = new Movie();
                movie.setTitle(title);
                movie.setYear(year);

                titleName.setText(title);

            }

            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```